# Is Office.Interop backward compatible?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, com-interop, excel-interop

Does referencing **Office.Interop 14.0** allow me to automate Office 2003, 2007, and 2010?

I asked because I am unable to reference multiple directives for different Interop version (and I can no longer download trails of older office to check its compatibility).

(Office.Interop 12.0 failed against Office 2010 in my application.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes *but*...

You have to be careful not to use features of the API that the office version you're targeting doesn't support, or you'll get some very odd memory access exceptions thrown at you.

I'm using Interop 12 to target Outlook 2007 and 2010 without too many issues.

Comment: hmm. I use interop 12 on 2010 and it crash on excel application start up (before any macro is run), dunno how you get it to work..

Comment: Can you be more specific about what 'crash' means? Do you get an exception, application stall, does it only happen when you use the API or when your app first starts?